# Kubernetes: Access back end API from Angular

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a project that includes a Web API and an Angular front-end (NGINX). They are hosted on Google's Container Engine using Kubernetes. When I try to access the Web API service using `http://${service_name}/api` I get a `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

But, if I ssh into the Angular pod and curl that same address I get a response. How can I access the back-end API (from the browser using Angular) without exposing a public IP?

Comment: Just have Angular send the http reqests to a specific port at localhost and have NGINX proxy all of those ports to the API. The requests will appear to be to the current domain if the user looks at XHR, but will automatically be forward to your API domain/IP.

Comment: @Z.Bagley So, make calls to localhost:5001. Set the nginx server to listen on port 5001 (as well as the original port 80). Then proxy pass anything coming in on port 5001 to http://{service-name}?

Comment: Did you try to examine the network tab on web developer tools? Try going to the network tab, copy the xhr call's link address and pasting it into a new tab.. Make sure that it is the same url.

Comment: your `${service_name}` valid only with-in kubernetes cluster. if your trying to access outside of cluster it won't resolve the service_name.

Comment: @RaefKandil the issue is comment stated below you.

Comment: @sfgroups I understand that. What's the fix??

Comment: I can think of two options. 1. Expose your service to NodePort and use one of node DNS name:Service IP in your URL (service_name). 2. Configure the Ingress for your service then use the ingress DNS for service_name.